# Equivalent definitions for subgraph

Tags: graphs

I know that a graph G' is a subgraph for G if V(G')⊆V(G) and E(G')⊆E(G).

Today my professor wrote that G' is a subgraph for G if G' is a graph and V(G')⊆V(G), and then he told us that this definition is equivalent to the one we've seen before (= the first line in this post).

However, I don't think that these definitions are equivalent. In fact, if this is G:

```
       2
     /   \
    1     3
```

and this is G':

```
    1 - 3
```

we have that G' is a subgraph for G according to the second definition (wrong), while it is not according to the first one (right).

Am I missing something or was the professor wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative definition that you attribute to your professor is wrong, as your counterexample clearly shows.

I hope your professor actually said something else and you misunderstood him/her!